# How would I go about parsing string literal segments in a string?

Tags: python, parsing

If I have a string like

```
'Hello, my name is "Bob" "I am 20 years old" I like to play "football"'
```

how would I go about parsing it in a way that gives me

```
["Bob", "I am 20 years old", "football"]
```

as a Python list?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a regex with the [non-greedy qualifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply look for paired double quotes with anything except a double quote between them.

```
for match in re.finditer(r'"[^"]+"', text):
    print(match)
```

Answer (score 0):

The python `string.split()` method allows you to specify a character that the string is divided by. The resulting array doesn't remove the other content of the string, however you can use a quick for loop to select just the elements you're interested in.

```
>>> a = 'Hello my name is "Bob" "I am 20 years old" I like to play "football"'
>>> b = a.split('"')
>>> b
['Hello my name is ', 'Bob', ' ', 'I am 20 years old', ' I like to play ', 'football', '']
>>> c = []
>>> for i in range(len(b)):
        if i%2 == 1:
            c.append(b[i])
>>> c
['Bob', 'I am 20 years old', 'football']
```

'''